# Repport Builder - SSRS: How do you reference a value in column group

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a dataset that is generating several columns when using the column grouping for one of the fields. Please see image below for example:

[image: Example]

I need to add a additional column and reference the value in `column CD` for each row so that I could calculate the ratio of value for `CD` to Total for that row.

I have tried using 
`=SUM(IIF(Column2="CD",Column3,0))` which did not work. There must be some alternate way to referring to the column group which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This works when an additional column is added off of the column group and not past the total column. When adding column, you should see the option of inside or outside the group. As long as you see that, you should be able to use the formula above and reference a column value.